# What would be the difference between using the await keyword vs. the Task.Wait() method on a CPU bound task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

What would be the *mechanical* difference between?

```
async void LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(CPUBoundWork);
    
    // Do IO bound work
    await DoIOAsync();
}
```

and

```
async void LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    var cpuTask = Task.Run(CPUBoundWork);
    
    cpuTask.Wait();
    
    // Do IO bound work
    await DoIOAsync();
}
```

I understand that logically, both would result in the same flow-of-control. Under both the cases, the `DoIOAsync` method would get called only after the `CPUBoundWork` task has completed execution.

However, would there be a difference in terms of the scheduling of the CPU task in both the cases?

**Update**

Please confirm if my uneducated rumination about the code above is correct.

It is my understanding that `await` disassociates any affinity between the thread and the task that was being run on the thread. While this works great for I/O requests, since you now re-use an I/O thread that was blocked on a network driver, you *want* to maintain thread-affinity for CPU bound work.

While await destroys this affinity, the `Wait()` method, I am not sure but purely guessing, simply waits for the task to complete. If the task has not yet begun, it executes it on the current thread. If, however, the task had already begun earlier, it blocks the current thread, putting the current thread on the wait queue, the next time the thread that was executing the task on which `Wait` is called comes around and finishes its work, it signals the waiting thread and the waiting thread continues. Therefore, thread-affinity for the task is maintained when calling `Wait`.

Of course, all of this is mere speculation. I want someone to confirm it.

Comment: As a side-note, [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Avoid Async Void") is intended for event handlers, and the `LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync` doesn't look like an event handler. So most likely the code snippets demonstrate erroneous usage of `async void`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It is my understanding that await disassociates any affinity between the thread and the task that was being run on the thread.

No, that's not at all what happens.

First, `await` causes nothing to run, nothing to be "scheduled". The scheduling (if any) and running (if any) are already in progress before you get to the `await`.

`await` is an "asynchronous wait"; that is, it asynchronously waits for the task to complete. "Asynchronous" here means "without blocking the *current* thread".

I have a more detailed [introduction to `async` and `await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog.

> I understand that logically, both would result in the same flow-of-control.

Not really. The `Wait` will block the current thread, while the `await` will not.

> Under both the cases, the DoIOAsync method would get called only after the CPUBoundWork task has completed execution.

This is correct.

> However, would there be a difference in terms of the scheduling of the CPU task in both the cases?

No, in both cases the scheduling is done by `Task.Run`, not `Wait` or `await`.

> While this works great for I/O requests, since you now re-use an I/O thread that was blocked on a network driver, you want to maintain thread-affinity for CPU bound work.

If you want to stay on the same thread, then you can't use `Task.Run`. You'd have to just call `CPUBoundWork` directly.

> the Wait() method, I am not sure but purely guessing, simply waits for the task to complete. If the task has not yet begun, it executes it on the current thread.

There's a bit more to it than that. Sometimes it will, sometimes it won't. In the code you posted, it usually won't (because `CPUBoundWork` will have already started).

> Therefore, thread-affinity for the task is maintained when calling Wait.

Again, this is a simplification. If by "thread affinity" you mean that the thread is the same before and after the `Wait`, then yes, that's correct.

However, [blocking on tasks within an asynchronous method can be dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html); as I describe on my blog, you can get into deadlock situations. If you're considering using `Task.Run` in conjunction with `async`, please review my [`Task.Run` etiquette guide](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will study more and come back to re-read your answer.

Comment: You kinda glossed over the question statement that "you now re-use an I/O thread that was blocked on a network driver"... probably good to recap ["There is no thread"](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) (for in-flight overlapped I/O)

Comment: @StephenCleary: Actually. what I wrote in the **Updated** section is precisely what you are saying. I think it is a matter of using different words. I should have clarified further. I will come back to add more to this question and ask what I am trying to ask after reading all the documentation and the articles you and others link to.

Comment: Or may be what you are saying is different but at this time, to my uninformed mind, it looks like what I am saying is what you are saying in different words. At any rate, I will need to come back to this question after some more study on this subject.

Comment: @StephenCleary: I read your philosophical account titled, "There is no thread!" and I believe you're saying what I was saying but in very different words, and with much detail and clarity as to what happens in the OS and the device driver. I liked your explanation and found that article to be very useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @StephenClearly I understand a little more now what `await` does after having reproduced the state machine it produces, by hand. So, my assumption that *await disassociates thread affinity* is not correct, as you seem to rightly indicate in your answer. Thanks much.

Comment: @StephenCleary if I place in my code an `await MyTask()` and right in the next line a `await MyTask2()` my second task (MyTask2()) will only be called after MyTask() finish, right? The only thing is that by using `await` instead of `wait`, every processes running in the same thread, will not be affected(paused) because I did not block the curr. thread, right?

Comment: Yes. See my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to understand what is happening, if you "convert" the async..await structure to Task and ContinueWith.

What I mean? Your first code:

```
async void LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(CPUBoundWork);

    // Do IO bound work
    await DoIOAsync();
}
```

will be converted to:

```
Task LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(CPUBoundWork)
        .ContinueWith(t => {
            // Do IO bound work
            DoIOAsync();
        }).Unwrap();
}
```

so it returns immediately to the caller with a Task-chain.

Your second code:

```
async void LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    var cpuTask = Task.Run(CPUBoundWork);

    cpuTask.Wait();

    // Do IO bound work
    await DoIOAsync();
}
```

will be converted to:

```
Task LongIOBoundWorkWithSomeCPUBoundWorkAsWellAsync()
{
    var cpuTask = Task.Run(CPUBoundWork);

    cpuTask.Wait();

    // Do IO bound work
    return DoIOAsync();
}
```

so it waits until the first Task is ready, and then returns to the caller with the Task of DoIOAsync.

So the two approaches are definitve not the same! The second code will block the caller until CPUBoundWork is ready.

Comment: Thank you. Thing is: I know all this and wrote *exactly* all this in my **Update** section of the question. When I said *logical* flow-of-control, I did not mean *what will happen internally*. Instead, I meant *in what sequence what method will be executed*. And what you all are explaining is what I meant by *mechanical* difference. And what everyone, including Stephen Clearey is saying in his answer is precisely what I wrote in my **Update** section in the question above, albeit in different words. It's a difference of words here, not of opinions.

Comment: @lvoros, you need `.Unwrap()` after `.ContinueWith(...)` in the first example to have the same effect.  Moreover, `await` does more than that: it checks if the task has already completed, and if so, continues execution.  So, in essence, an `async` method may return a task at any `await` or, ultimately, on return or throw, returning an already completed task.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've corrected it. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as scheduling goes, there won't really be a difference between the contexts once you reach `DoIOAsync`, other than the first one could possibly be on a different thread.

The main difference here is that `Wait()` blocks a thread, while `await` allows that thread to be re-used. Blocking a thread is way more expensive than switching to a new task. You're also potentially putting more pressure on the thread pool to grow.

Of course, that's all *if* you reach `DoIOAsync`. Mixing async and sync is a recipe for deadlocks and generally not recommended if you're not absolutely sure what's going on.

Comment: I have updated the question with a theory I have. It would be nice if someone could confirm or invalidate my assumptions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will study more and come back to re-read your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are understand jet after 2 answers that difference in your case is that Wait() block second variant. But - in your case you don't return any values from awaiting function CPUBoundWork!  But if you will return some values ( for example int) - than your code will be like that:

```
    Task<int> cpuTask = Task.Run(() => CPUBoundWork);
    ... // here we can do anything before CPUBoundWork return result
    var r = await cpuTask;// we will be here only after CPUBoundWork return result
```