# Why do we need async function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am wondering why we need async function in c#. I did my research and it looks like an async function is used if one has an IO-bound task that one wants to wait for without blocking.

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static async Task DoIO()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, new CancellationTokenSource().Token);
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoIO();
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        while (true);
        // Output: Start \n DONE
    }
}
```

The other case, is when a CPU-bound task is to be started, but we don't want to wait for it. It should run in the background. It would look exactly like the previous code block, but replace `DoIO()` with `DoCPU()`, a function that makes heavy computations.

```
public static async Task DoCPU()
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
        // Heavy computation
    });
}
```

In both cases the keyword is **"without waiting"**. We want to call async methods without blocking the caller method.

Now this is where my **question** comes in: Why do I get the warning **"Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call?"** Isn't the whole purpose of async function to **NOT** await? Otherwise why not just use "regular" synchronous methods which block by default?

Comment: "Await" in this sense doesn't mean "block everything and do nothing until this returns".  It's more like "put the rest of this function in another context and pick it up when this returns, until then the caller is free to do other things".  The caller may also await, its caller may await, etc. all the way up to the framework/host internals.  But at some point up that chain is something which will be free to switch to another task while the IO task is happening.  For example, a web server which is now free to handle another request while the previous request waits for a DB operation.

Comment: @David That makes sense. One would have a chain of async functions that await each other and at the end (actually the start) of the chain there is the (sync?) function that fired up the entire chain. This function, you argue, can do something else in the meantime, right? But how? If it calls the first async function of the chain and awaits for it, then it can't do anything else until the task is finished, and if it doesn't await, then you get the warning that I showed. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Skander: I would say that in the *vast* majority of cases (at least in my experience) it's a non-issue.  The top-level functionality that coordinates tasks/threads/etc. is internal to the framework.  But you certainly *can* manage tasks yourself if you like.  One common example is to collect multiple tasks into an array (of `Task` or `Task<>` objects) and [await them in parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall).  Which is still *a kind* of "awaiting", but structured differently.

Comment: To understand why it is needed, you should maybe know how it works. A great article about how it is working can be found here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/

Comment: `and awaits for it` - "awaits" does not refer to being busy actively waiting, it's "returning to the caller, telling them to resume when ready". The beginning of the async chain returns to its caller, which is the framework code that you have not written. That framework code is then free to resume whatever tasks it has beside you. E.g. for a Windows Forms app, that would be [pumping the messages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223270/11683). The waiting itself [does not require attendance](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @David Thanks for response. Actually in my case it's really not any framework that's handling that. It's me. I was a given a task in my company to fix a broken pr (so no redesigning possible). What we have is a sync function that wants to call an async function without waiting for it (Make the async function do its work in the background and move on to something else). But it bothers me to get the warning. In the .Net docs about the warning I read "because no Await operator ... the program continues without waiting... **In most cases, that behavior isn't expected.**". How is it not expected?

Comment: Would you like to clarify if your question is 1) about the [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014) warning, 2) about the behavior of `async` or 3) about the behavior of `await`?

Comment: @Skander: *"in my case it's really not any framework that's handling that"* - In this case "the framework" includes the application hosting technology you're using (ASP.NET, WinForms, etc.) and the .NET framework itself.  As for the rest of that comment... That problem isn't what's being described in the question.  Perhaps you instead meant to ask a question about that specific concrete issue, and not just asking how async/await works **in general**?

Comment: @Skander Because the assumption is that you are likely to be interested in the result of the operation that you have started. If that is not the case and you actually don't care about what result that task returns, when it completes, and whether it throws exceptions, the that's called [fire and forget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46053175/11683), and you can suppress the warning.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias My understanding is: the purpose of async methods is to perform jobs (either IO of CPU bound) in the background/ without blocking the main thread. Then my question is: if that's the case then why does that warning exist.

Comment: So your question is about the warning, and it is based on the assumption that `async` methods [are running on different threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27265818/does-the-use-of-async-await-create-a-new-thread "Does the use of async/await create a new thread?"), correct?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am not assuming that async methods are running on different threads. They do give the impression though (apart from the avoided race conditions). My understanding is, function A is sync, funciton B is async. Function A calls B **without** waiting. Then the same thread will start executing B until reaching await, then the control is given back to A to carry on with its execution, until the await from B is finished, then the thread (or another one) goes back to B. Had A awaited for B, and had A been the main thread, the main thread would be literally blocked.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias What I am asserting is: if I am someone who hates warnings, I will follow the tip and always await async methods. And if async methods are always awaited for by the caller, whenever they are called, wouldn't it be the same if I replace all of them with regular sync methods?

Comment: @Skander To answer that question, create a new Windows Forms app and put two buttons on the form. In one button's Click handler place `Thread.Sleep(10000);`. In the other, `await Task.Delay(10000);`. Press one button, wait a bit and press another. Observe if the result is the same or not.

Comment: You may want to edit the question and clarify what the question is about. Currently the question is quite ambiguous. The title asks why the `async` keyword is needed, and the body asks why the CS4014 warning is needed. Maybe what you really want to know is how to suppress the CS4014 warning. You could also consider posting a new question and deleting this one, in case you judge that clearing the misunderstandings that this question has created is too difficult.

Comment: Btw the purpose of the comments on this site, according to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), is to request clarifications from the author, or leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the question. The clarifications are supposed to be included in the question, not posted as comments. The comments are not considered part of the question, and could be removed by the moderators at any time. Answering a question does not require to read the comments first.

Comment: @Skander if u were working on a GUI framework like `Windows Forms` or even `WPF` , ... the things were more obvious while u were trying to do this computation overhead in a single threaded application. By using `async/await` u won't experience any GUI hanging anymore.

Comment: Does [What would be the difference between using the await keyword vs. the Task.Wait() method on a CPU bound task?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37603609) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't the whole purpose of async function to NOT await?

*Waiting* and *awaiting* are different things. In the context of .Net `Wait` is a synchronous operation that blocks the thread. While `await` is asynchronous and lets the thread do other thing. The magic of async/await lets you write asynchronous code in almost the same way as synchronous code.

Consider two equivalent programs:

```
public static async Task DoIO()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    await DoIO();
}
```

and

```
public static void DoIO()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("End");
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    DoIO();
}
```

For a console program these are directly equivalent. And Using the synchronous variant is perfectly fine.

If we remove the `await` in the Main method from the asynchronous variant the programs are no longer equivalent. The program will print "start", create a timer that elapses after 1s, and then exit once the main thread reaches the end of the Main-method. never printing "End". That is the reason for the warning you get, not awaiting a task is an easy mistake to make, and fairly often a bug.

If this was a UI program instead there would be a difference. If you use `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread, or any other blocking operation, your UI will freeze, and fairly soon windows will show the "application unresponsive" message. Async/await makes it easy to do slow stuff while still keeping the UI responsive, and still ensure that only the UI thread updates the UI.

Another common usage of asynchronous programming is servers, where you might have thousands of concurrent requests that are all waiting for the database. Using a thread for each of these requests would be a waste of memory. If you use async/await you only need a thread when actually use it to compute something.

You can also use async/await to do multiple IO operations concurrently, by starting multiple operations, and only doing the await once all are started. But you need to be a bit careful when doing this, since it is possible to cause various kinds of contention issues that may result in *reduced* performance.

Answer (score 2):

Disregarding the comments, I'll answer to this:

> Now this is where my question comes in: Why do I get the warning "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call?" Isn't the whole purpose of async function to NOT await? Otherwise why not just use "regular" synchronous methods which block by default?

You seem to have a bunch of misconceptions.

First of all, you do *not* await a method call but the Task returned by it.

In other words: You do not *have to* do this:

```
var result = await DoSomethingAsync();
```

You can very well do this:

```
var task = DoSomethingAsync();

// do something else

var result = await task;
```

*Your* code does not do any of these. Hence, you get a warning about that fact.

I hope the second snippet already shows you why `await`ing a `Task` is not at all the same as blocking. You cannot *defer* unwrapping the context of a synchronous blocking method. In other words: you cannot split a sync call like shown above.

And it also doesn't matter if it's a `Task<T>` or a `Task` in that respect. The only difference is the lack of a result value for the latter.

Also consider that a "fire&forget" async Task that is never awaited may still be running / awaiting IO when the program exits with all sideeffects that come with that.

Sometimes, this is intentional and known to have no critical sideeffects. In such case, you are free to suppress the warning.

Comment: @Skander: Not part of the answer, but I'd like to introduce you to [Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) posts on that topic.